# Bokeh - CustomJS data with Python functions to Download data and Alert users

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to create a bokeh server (running with Python -m bokeh serve my_pythonfile.py) where I let the user modify some data that I want to use in a CustomJS function. I tried to make a simple example of my class here:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.data = 0
    self.click_me = self._get_click_button()
    self.save_data = self._get_save_data()

def _get_click_button(self) -> Button:
    click_me = Button(label='Add data')
    click_me.on_click(self.add_data)
    return click_me

def self.add_data(self):
    self.data += 1

def _get_save_data(self) -> Button:
    save = Button(label='Save data')
    callback = CustomJS(args={'data': self.return_data()}, code="""console.log(data);""")
    save.js_on_click(callback)
    return save

def return_data(self) -> int:
    return self.data
```

When I press on the `Save data` button I always get 0 in the console, I understand why but I don't know how to get the actual number of `self.data`, any ideas/tips?

The actual things that I want to do is to let the user download some data (a json file) and one solution that came to mind was use the html5 keyword `download`. In another case I wanted to use the `alert` keyword to let the user know that he have entered some bad data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native `int` value is not synced between the Bokeh server and the client.

`args={'data': self.return_data()}` is essentially `args={'data': 0}`.

To sync an object between the server and client, subclass `Model` and use it.

```py
from bokeh.core.properties import Int
from bokeh.models import Model
from bokeh.util.compiler import TypeScript


class MyModel(Model):
    __implementation__ = TypeScript("""
    import { Model } from "model";
    export class MyModel extends Model {
        constructor(attrs: any) {
            super(attrs);
        }
        static init_MyModel() {
            this.define(({ Int }) => ({
                data: [Int, 0] as any,
            }));
        }
    }
    """)

    data = Int
```

Usage:

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.model = MyModel(data=0)  # Modified
    self.click_me = self._get_click_button()
    self.save_data = self._get_save_data()

def _get_click_button(self) -> Button:
    click_me = Button(label='Add data')
    click_me.on_click(self.add_data)
    return click_me

def add_data(self):
    self.model.data += 1  # Modified

def _get_save_data(self) -> Button:
    save = Button(label='Save data')
    callback = CustomJS(args={'model': self.model}, code="""console.log(model.data);""")  # Modified
    save.js_on_click(callback)
    return save

# def return_data(self) -> int: # Removed
#     return self.data          # Removed
```